# Firebase Cloud Functions - How to deserialize map for android Map

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm just getting into firebase's cloud functions and am trying to deserialize a map as is done in this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

how do I get the values from the map passed to the server to display in the log instead of reading out [object Object]?

Here is what I have so far:

**android app**

```
mRequestApprovedButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: mRequestApproved clicked");
    private void createChatKitRoomWithUsers() {


        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("Owner", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
        data.put("Renter", mRenterString);

        mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("createPusherChatRoomHTTPSCall").call(data);

    }
});
```

**Firebase Cloud Function**

```
exports.createPusherChatRoomHTTPSCall = functions.https.onCall((data, context) =>{
    console.log("context.auth.id: " + context.auth.uid); // grabs currently logged in user's id.
    console.log("context.auth.token.name: " + context.auth.token.name); // grabs currently logged in user's name.

    console.log("data: " + data.toString()); // returns: "data: [object Object]"
    console.log("data: " + data); // data: [object Object]
    console.log("data: " + data.parse("Owner"));  // doesnt seem to work

})
```

this is what it looks like in firebase functions log
[image]

any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is going to contain properties for each of the key/value pairs that are present in the Map that you passed from the client.

```
const owner = data.Owner
const render = data.Renter
```

You will get better log output if you *don't use string concatenation*, and instead log the object directly:

```
console.log(data)
```

or:

```
console.log("data:", data)
```